# How to select Viewmodel in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

Here is my table from which I am getting my friends list. For this my model is as follows:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid UserRelationshipId { get; set; }
public string Id { get; set; }
public string SecondUserId { get; set; }

// 0 for Request pending
// 1 for Request Accepted
// 2 for Declined
// 3 For Blocked
public int Status { get; set; }
public string ActionUserId { get; set; } // who have taken action against the status

[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual ApplicationUser Users { get; set; }
```

Now I am using a query where I have to get my friend list:

```
string LoginId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var Searchuser = from u in db.UserRelationships where u.Id == LoginId && u.Status == 1                            
                 select new UserViewModel
                 {
                     Fname = u.Users.FirstName,
                     Lname = u.Users.LastName,
                     Gender = u.Users.Gender,
                     Id = u.Id,
                     CurrentCity = u.Users.CurrentCity
                 };
```

I am getting data of my own because I have compared my LoginId with the id. The problem is how I will get the data for SecondUserId? What will be the query for it? I can do this by using a join query but I want to avoid it. Is there any way without a join query?

Comment: Please can you make your question more clear, I'm confused.

Comment: @Coulton I Have Mention in model Please check There is attribute seconduserID which is the id who have send me friendRequest or Vice-versa.So u want to get the list of that in my search where id will be the loginuserId

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  I still don't understand the question though :(

Comment: @Coulton Forget that Code You just check Model Where id is the loginId and seconduserId who are my friend now how to get their data from db.users as i have taken ID as Foreign Key.

Comment: Just do a second query?

Comment: @Coulton i can get this list by using Join with both tables and i want to avoid it and want to get data by foriegn key Only.

Comment: `var user = DbContext.Users.Find(seconduserId)`

Comment: @Coulton How to use Didn't get it?

Comment: @Coulton Could you post the Answer for it as i will upvote it and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by performing a second query:

```
string LoginId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

// Get the user relationship entity
var userRelationship = (from u in db.UserRelationships
                       where u.Id == LoginId && u.Status == 1
                       select u).FirstOrDefault();

// Get the second user, using the values in the user relationship entity
var secondUser = db.Users.Find(userRelationship.SecondUserId);

// Generate the view model
var viewModel =  new UserViewModel()
                 {
                     Fname = userRelationship.Users.FirstName,
                     Lname = userRelationship.Users.LastName,
                     Gender = userRelationship.Users.Gender,
                     Id = userRelationship.Id,
                     CurrentCity = userRelationship.Users.CurrentCity
                 };
```

Comment: I am getting same result the view model returning the details of loginuser Id ony